# File card Resizing

Tags: lightning, css

Does anyone know how to resize a filecard lightning component , i tried to make it of an avatar size  ?

My component looks like that : 
[image]

I did try to add some css as i followed the same thing in here : 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005cr4QAA

But it didnt affect anything. Any ideas ?

This is my component code :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller ="InboxAttachmentApex" access="global" >

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.getInboxAttach}" value="{!this}"  />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>


<aura:attribute name="FileList" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="InboxList" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="headerTitle" type="Aura.Component[]">
    <h2> <b>Pièces Jointes </b> </h2>
</aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="selectedDocumentId" type="string"/>
<aura:attribute name="hasModalOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>


<lightning:card  class="slds-text-heading_small"  title="{!v.headerTitle}" iconName="standard:file"  >
      <div  aura:id="listFiles"   >

                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.InboxList}" var="inbox">              
                                <ul class="slds-has-dividers_bottom-space">
                                    <li class="slds-item" >
                                        <a data-Id="{!inbox.ContentDocumentId}"> 
                                        <lightning:tile  label="{!inbox.Title}" href="{!'/lightning/r/ContentDocument/'+inbox.ContentDocumentId+'/view'}" >
                                            <aura:set attribute="media">
                                                <section onclick="{!c.getSelected}">
                                                   <div class="de"> 
                                                     <lightning:fileCard fileId="{!inbox.ContentDocumentId}" description="{!inbox.Title}" hideDescription = "true" />  
                                                    </div>

                                                    </section>
                                                </aura:set>
                                            <ul class="slds-list_horizontal slds-has-dividers_right">
                                                <li class="slds-item">  <ui:outputDate  class="slds-truncate " value="{!inbox.LastModifiedDate}"  format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/></li>
                                                <li class="slds-item">{!inbox.ContentSize } Bytes</li>
                                                <li class="slds-item">{!inbox.FileExtension } </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </lightning:tile> </a>
                                    </li>               
                                </ul>
                        </aura:iteration>


        </div>
</lightning:card>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.hasModalOpen}">
    <section onclick="{!c.closeModel}"
             role="dialog"
             aria-modal="true"
             class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium slds-text-align_center"
                 style="background: transparent;">
                <div style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left">
                    <!--<lightning:fileCard> to preview file using content document Id -->
                    <lightning:fileCard fileId="{!v.selectedDocumentId}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</aura:if>
```

and my controller code :

```
({
getInboxAttach: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchInboxAttach(component,event,helper);
},

/*call apex controller method "fetchContentDocument" to get salesforce file records*/
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getInboxAttachApex");
    var opportunityId= component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({
            opportunityId: opportunityId
        });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set('v.InboxList', response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);  
},
getSelected : function(component,event,helper){
    // display modle and set seletedDocumentId attribute with selected record Id   
    component.set("v.hasModalOpen" , true);
    console.log('######################################'+event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-Id"));  
    component.set("v.selectedDocumentId" , event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-Id")); 

},
closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
    // for Close Model, set the "hasModalOpen" attribute to "FALSE"  
    component.set("v.hasModalOpen", false);
    component.set("v.selectedDocumentId" , null); 
}
```

})

helper code :

```
({
fetchInboxAttach : function(component,event,helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getInboxAttachApex");
        var opportunityId= component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({
            opportunityId: opportunityId
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
        if (state=='SUCCESS'){
            var inboxlist =response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.InboxList",inboxlist);
            component.set("v.imageSrc", "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + inboxlist.ContentDocumentId);

            console.log('Inbox'+inboxlist);
        } else {
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }                    
    });
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Css code:

```
.THIS.de{
height:10px !important; 
width:10px !important;
background:#000000 !important;
width: 150px;
border: 1px solid black; 
max-width: 100% !important;
position: absolute  !important; 
top: 0%  !important; ;
left: 0%  !important; 
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)  !important; 
-ms-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)  !important; 
transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)  !important; 
max-width: 100%  !important;
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add code snippet instead of screenshot? As one cannot copytext from , its hard to reporduce it at our end?

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Little update to my issue , i did some research i found this solution :
So i did  retrieve my filecard component and replace it with an img tag , see the following line :

```
<img src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB120BY90&amp;versionId={!inbox.Id}"/>
```

Availabes Sizes:

> THUMB120BY90
>   THUMB240BY180
>   THUMB720BY480